# Are multi-arity anonymous functions possible in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I am in a situation where I can only create anonymous functions that are assigned to a variable, like this:

```
Foo = fun(X) -> X end.
```

I know if you are in a module you can do something like this:

```
foo(X) -> X.
foo(X, Y) -> X + Y.
% i.e. foo(3) = 3, foo(3,4) = 7
```

My questions is: **is this possible with anonymous functions?**

A blog post (that I've now lost sorry) led me to think you could do something like this:

```
Foo = fun(X) -> X;
         (X, Y) -> X + Y
      end.
```

But that does not work, as I get a "head mismatch" error.

Comment: You can only do that for pattern matching, i.e. `Foo = fun({x,y}) -> one; ({a,b}) -> two end`, I can't think of a way you can do what you want unless you just accept a list, like `Foo = fun([X]) -> X; ([X,Y]) -> {X,Y} end`, calling `Foo([a])` and `Foo([a,b])`, etc.

Comment: Yeah, apart from accepting a list I can't find anything. In the real-world situation each of the variables passed are different things, so one option would be to pass a proplist (I _think_ that's an idiomatic map, I'm new to Erlang) and do it that way. Make your comment an answer if you want sweet sweet karma :P

Comment: It's a very interesting question actually, I never noticed or thought about this...

Comment: Name + Arity is the *identity* of the function. In the case of an anonymous function you lack a name. In a real program *you should never have a case where you don't know the arity of a call you are making*. How would this situation even exist? The reason so many lambdas of arity 1 pop up in FP is because of list (that is, iterating one-by-one). How would you even write code where you don't know the arity of a call to an anonymous function? Even if you could *why* would you do that? Keep in mind that you *can* write properly variadic functions by using list or tuple parameters, though.

Comment: @zxq9 I'm not sure I understand you. It's not that I don't know what the arity is, it's that having to name functions differently because of their arity is an ugly throwback to the 80s. If you're wondering why I can only use anonymous functions, it's because I'm writing code that ultimately gets injected into a running process (CouchDB native erlang filters) and the tool-what-does-the-injecting expects that I pass it exactly one function.

Comment: @SCdF `{M,F,A}` is one argument too of course. If you have control over the passing of the function AND control over the calling of it, which I presume you must, or else you'd be conforming to a specific API / interface, then you could pass an `{M,F,A}` or `{M,F}` value. This also means you don't have stange anonymous functions floating around, which can wreck havock when you do a node/release upgrade if they hang around for long enough.

Comment: @SCdF What is "addition"? It has a specific arity (2). What is "summation"? It is an operation *over a list of values* (of list(N) -- we don't care how long). That these are different *is critical* in a programming paradigm that is based on *functions* as the principal concept of sequential evaluation. Conflating the ideas is what you are used to -- tl;dr: this is called "technical debt", and it will always bite you in the ass eventually.

Comment: @zxq9 I always worry that when I use simpler examples to explain things people will project a little too far into the example. The **real** usage I have for it is a function that wraps proplists:get_value/3 with some checks. The last parameter to that function is a Default, and proplists:get_value/2 defaults the default to 'undefined'. I'd like to have the flexibilty of get_value, but with a anon function.

Comment: @Michael Yep, I've considered passing a tuple instead, as it's definitely an option :-)

Comment: @SCdF (Btw, simple examples are indeed tricky.) Use a part of Erlang that can *match on the shape of the returned data*: cases and function heads. For example: `fun(X) -> case proplists:get_value(X, ThingYouAreClosingOver) of undefined -> mitigation_for_not_found_case(X); Value -> do_stuff_with(Value) end end` There is a place in Erlang for these specific conditions -- it is baked into the language already. That place is *not* overloading of functions by arity. (Instead we essentially overload by type; a controllable phenomenon via matching and guards.) That is what I meant about "proper"ness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only pattern match:

```
Foo = fun ({x,y}) -> one;
          ({a,b}) -> two
          end
```

You could just accept a list:

```
Foo = fun ([X])   -> X;
          ([X,Y]) -> {X,Y}
          end
```

I was too curious not to look at the performance, so I had a quick go at benchmarking it. This is far from perfect, and intended only to be indicative of what might be, and really one should calculate a mean, standard deviation, average, min and max, but I opted for a minimum time to do 1,000,000 calls.

I used this code:

```
-module(foo).

-export([run/1, norm1/0, norm2/0, norm3/0, norm4/0, list1/0, list2/0, list3/0, list4/0]).

-define(COUNT, 1000000).


run(F) ->
    T = lists:foldl(
        fun(_,Min) ->
            T = ?MODULE:F(),
            if T < Min -> T; true -> Min end
            end,
        ?MODULE:F(),
        lists:seq(1,99)
        ),
    T
    .

norm1() ->
    Foo = fun(N) -> N * N end,
    {T,_} = timer:tc(fun() ->
        lists:map(fun(A) -> Foo(A) end, lists:seq(1,?COUNT))
        end),
    T
    .

norm2() ->
    Foo = fun(N, M) -> N * M end,
    {T,_} = timer:tc(fun() ->
        lists:map(fun(A) -> Foo(A,A) end, lists:seq(1,?COUNT))
        end),
    T
    .

norm3() ->
    Foo = fun(M, N, M) -> N * M end,
    {T,_} = timer:tc(fun() ->
        lists:map(fun(A) -> Foo(A,A,A) end, lists:seq(1,?COUNT))
        end),
    T
    .

norm4() ->
    Foo = fun(N, M, N, M) -> N * M end,
    {T,_} = timer:tc(fun() ->
        lists:map(fun(A) -> Foo(A,A,A,A) end, lists:seq(1,?COUNT))
        end),
    T
    .

list1() ->
    Foo = fun([N]) -> N * N end,
    {T,_} = timer:tc(fun() ->
        lists:map(fun(A) -> Foo([A]) end, lists:seq(1,?COUNT))
        end),
    T
    .

list2() ->
    Foo = fun([N, M]) -> N * M end,
    {T,_} = timer:tc(fun() ->
        lists:map(fun(A) -> Foo([A,A]) end, lists:seq(1,?COUNT))
        end),
    T
    .

list3() ->
    Foo = fun([_, N, M]) -> N * M end,
    {T,_} = timer:tc(fun() ->
        lists:map(fun(A) -> Foo([A,A,A]) end, lists:seq(1,?COUNT))
        end),
    T
    .

list4() ->
    Foo = fun([_, _, N, M]) -> N * M end,
    {T,_} = timer:tc(fun() ->
        lists:map(fun(A) -> Foo([A,A,A,A]) end, lists:seq(1,?COUNT))
        end),
    T
    .
```

This is the result:

```
1> foo:run(norm1).
44820
2> foo:run(norm2).
48959
3> foo:run(norm3).
50328
4> foo:run(norm4).
50402
5> 
5> foo:run(list1).
50463
6> foo:run(list2).
58948
7> foo:run(list3).
60829
8> foo:run(list4).
86604
9>
```

Performance is obviously going to depend on how long the list is, as one would expect, since it has to work through the list, and the penalty is greater than with a normal call.

The performance difference doesn't look so great to me though that it's worth worrying about in most situations if it is the correct solution, at least, if you don't expect to have too many arguments in your lists!

Answer (score 7):

The simple and correct answer is **no, you can't**. This is actually quite logical as when you do

```
foo(X) -> X.
foo(X, Y) -> X + Y.
```

you are actually creating **two** functions: `foo/1`, a function of one argument; and `foo/2`, another function which has two arguments. They are **not** the same `foo`. This maps directly to anonymous functions (`funs`) so you would need to create two different funs, one of one argument and the other of two arguments.

The "head mismatch" error is complaining about the different number of arguments.